# How to lock primitive static fields in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I know you can obtain a lock instance members like so:

```
SyncLock [Object]
    [Object].mutate()
End SyncLock
```

but how do you lock static fields?

(e.g. to make `[Object's Class].[static field] = [new value]` thread-safe)

I can't find anything online for VB.

*The field is a primitive type.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the object is a reference type, you can simply lock that object:

```
SyncLock [Class].[Object]
    ' … edit object
End SyncLock
```

Depending on your situation this may be the correct thing to do. However, be aware that this should ideally only be done on private objects, *inside* the class. Otherwise you have no guarantee that every client is going to lock the object correctly.

Whether your field is a primitive type isn’t important here, except that most primitive types are *value types*, and you cannot lock those. So, assuming that your type is a value type, you have to resort to a separate lock object as discussed in the comments:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly LockObj As New Object()
```

But, to clarify, locking on `LockObj` does *not* magically lock the rest of the class. It just provides a *protocol* for locking, and as long as every thread accessing the fields respects this protocol, you’re safe. Here’s an example:

```
Class Foo
    Private Shared ReadOnly LockObj As New Object()
    Private Shared MyValue As Integer = 1

    Public Shared Sub UpdateValue()
        SyncLock LockObj
            MyValue += 1
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ReadValue() As Integer
        SyncLock LockObj
            Return MyValue
        End SyncLock
    End Function
End Class
```

As long as every thread uses only `UpdateValue` and `ReadValue` to access `MyValue`, you’re safe from race conditions.

Comment: Will locking on `Private Shared ReadOnly lockObj As New Object()` lock all static fields of the class?

Comment: @JosephNields Noo, there’s no reason why it would. It will lock only that one object. However, if *every* thread which accesses any of the fields will first lock on this object then there’s no issue.

Comment: How can you lock a value type then? (PS, in Java you can synchronize access to static fields by just locking a private static object. Are you sure that's not the case in VB.NET?)

Comment: @Joseph From your description it sounds like you’re misunderstanding what you’re doing in Java, because the same is true there: if you do `synchronized (this.foo) { … }`, then access to `this.bar` elsewhere will *not* be synchronised. If, however, you lock on the same object everywhere before accessing any of the other member variables, you’re of course safe. But there’s no “magic” happening anywhere, access to `obj.bar` is only safe as long as the same thread has locked/synchronised `obj.foo` beforehand.

Comment: @Joseph I completely missed that part of your question, to be honest. Please see my updated answer, I hope that makes it clearer